# Django 1.9 Tutorial: No Tests are run

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am working through Django 1.9 [Django 1.9 Tutorial Part 5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial05/).

I am using Python 2.7.6 and Django 1.9.4.
The tree structure of my folders is:

```
django-mysite/
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.sublime-workspace
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-34.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
└── polls
    ├── admin.py
    ├── admin.pyc
    ├── apps.py
    ├── apps.pyc
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __init__.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── models.pyc
    ├── templates
    │   └── polls
    │       ├── detail.html
    │       ├── index.html
    │       ├── results.html
    │       └── tests.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── tests.pyc
    ├── urls.py
    ├── urls.pyc
    ├── views.py
    └── views.pyc
```

When I run tests through command:

```
python manage.py test polls
```

or

```
python manage.py test polls.tests
```

It does not run tests. The output is:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

The `tests.py` file has the code (as in tutorial)

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import Question
class QuestionMethodTests(TestCase):
    def test_was_published_recently_with_future_question(self):
        """
        was_published_recently() should return False for questions whose
        pub_date is in the future.
        """
        time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        future_question = Question(pub_date=time)
        self.assertEqual(future_question.was_published_recently(), False)
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Why do you need a `tests.py` in your `templates` folder? Maybe it is causing the problem.

Comment: How about running `python manage.py test polls` ? Is it running?

Comment: @sehrob nice catch. I used Sublime Text (Folder View) to create a  new .py file in /polls folder. It created same file in nested folder as well. Strange. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EdwinLunando Thanks a lot. Its working fine now. :)

Comment: To make sure the other can see, I will post it to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the tests.py from template/polls folder and then try.

To run the test, try `python manage.py test polls`

Comment: i was using this command. The problem was the duplicate file inside the inner polls folder.